# Spring OAuth2 pass Client-Id to get UserInfoUri

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to authenticate users with Spring OAuth2; however the server requires client id as a header `client-id` in order to get user info.

In other words request to userinfo endpoint requires the following headers:

```
Authorization: bearer token
Client-ID: myClientId
```

How can I make Spring add the `client-id` header to the request in order to get user info from server?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code showing how I retrieved an access token using the client credentails grant. It shows how you can set the client credentials in the Authorization header.

```
private CompletableFuture<String> getTokenFromAuthServer() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        String authTokenEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth-server/oauth/token";
        
        ***String credentials = OAUTH_CLIENT_USERNAME + ":" + OAUTH_CLIENT_PASSWORD;
        String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(credentials.getBytes()));
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);***
        
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        String access_token_url = authTokenEndpoint;
        access_token_url += "?grant_type=" + OAUTH_GRANT_TYPE;

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(access_token_url, HttpMethod.POST, 
                request, String.class);

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            map = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), Map.class);
            return map.get("access_token"); 
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            log.error("getTokenFromAuthServer: Exception.");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });             
}
```

The Base64 api is from the apache commons-lang3 library.

Comment: This makes sense; however, I want to override the default method that spring uses to call the UserInfo. That way, it will be called automatically after a token is generated. I looked at Spring API docs but I was not able to find which method that is, or how to configure that.